# trying to average column with CAST in PIVOT table- Incorrect syntax near '('

Tags: sql, datetime, pivot-table, average, dynamic-sql

I am trying the Pivot function to get the following table-
split rows of TagID into columns, the TagValue of each TagID and DATEADD TimeStamp to display avg values every 5 minutes:

```
     DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT   ',' + QUOTENAME(TagID) 
                    from table
                    group by TagID
                    order by TagID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


 set @query = 'SELECT  Top (500) DATEADD(minute,DATEDIFF(minute,0,TimeStamp)/5*5,0) AS TimeStamp, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select  TimeStamp, TagID , TagValue  
                from table
        Group By TimeStamp, TagID, TagValue


            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 AVG(CAST(TagValue) AS DECIMAL(18,2))
                for TagID in ( ' + @cols + ' )

            ) p '

        execute(@query)
```

I am trying to create avg for the column TagValue.

After I used the CAST function as you can see above, the query displayed:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

although I cannot find what is wrong and which exact syntax is incorrect.
Would really appreciate some help here as Management studio doesn't show where the problem is.

I looked up online and normally the avg function is used like this:
     AVG(TagValue) although it doesn't work on NVARCHAR column.

Comment: Before `execute(@query)`, please add `PRINT @query` and verify the computed dynamic query.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Thank you for your help! the Try_Cast worked

Answer (score 1):

There was syntax issue with the CAST statement, also minor changes were made to sub query table x - please try the below code

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT   ',' + QUOTENAME(TagID) 
                      FROM table
                      GROUP BY TagID
                      ORDER BY TagID
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT  TOP (500) DATEADD(minute,DATEDIFF(minute,0,TimeStamp)/5*5,0) AS TimeStamp, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select  TimeStamp, TagID , TRY_CAST(TagValue AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS [TagValue]
                from table
                Group By TimeStamp, TagID, TagValue
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                AVG(TagValue)
                for TagID in ( ' + @cols + ' )
            ) p '

EXEC(@query)
```

Comment: Perhaps the column TagValue might contain non-numeric values, I've amended the code to use TRY_CAST instead of CAST, try the updated code

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `AVG(CAST(TagValue AS DECIMAL(18,2)))` instead of
`AVG(CAST(TagValue) AS DECIMAL(18,2))` in the `pivot` block.

i.e, you are using `CAST(TagValue) AS DECIMAL(18,2))`, but it should be `CAST(TagValue AS DECIMAL(18,2))`

Comment: It keeps showing: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near '('

Answer (score 0):

You have issue with CAST Syntax. Use as below-

```
AVG(CAST(TagValue AS DECIMAL(18,2)))
```

You query shows table name is 'table'. Can you use the table name second bracket around as below-

```
FROM [table]
```

Comment: It keeps showing: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near '('

Comment: I did put the brackets as you suggested and it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you try with real column name first in place of dynamic column name to check all other syntax is as expected in the query or not.